# Ajax and JSON response bug in Internet Explorer (works in all other browsers)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, json

For some reason IE is asking us to download a file instead of running it as ajax. This works in all browsers except IE. I tried messing with the headers that it returns with no luck.

The function grabs form data then post's it the response is a can be an array of any number of items to be updated on the page.

Its not suppose to be file its suppose to be just a json response.

PHP

```
header('Content-type: application/json');

$error = "The Email and Password you entered could not be resolved.";
$elements[0]['target'] = '.error_report';
$elements[0]['action'] = 'inside';
$elements[0]['data'] = '<p>'.$error.'</p>';
$this->output->set_output(
  json_encode(array("elements" => $elements))
);
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function () {
            alert("Request was not successful. Please try again shortly.");
        }
    });

    $(document).ajaxSuccess(function (e, xhr, settings) {
        var response = xhr.responseText;
        if (settings.dataType != 'json') {
            return;
        };

        try {
            response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
            return;
        }

        if (response.elements instanceof Array) {
            var reqs = ['target', 'action'];
            var valid = true;
            for (var i=0;i<response.elements.length;i++) {
                var cur = response.elements[i];
                var sel;

                for (var j=0;j<reqs.length;j++) {
                    if (typeof cur[reqs[j]] !== "string") {
                        valid = false;
                        break;
                    };
                };

                if (!valid) {
                    continue;
                };

                sel = $(cur.target);
                switch (cur.action) {
                    case "inside":
                        sel.html(cur.data);
                    break;
                    case "instead":
                        sel.replaceWith(cur.data);
                    break;
                    case "remove":
                        sel.remove();
                    break;
                    case "refreshPage":
                        window.location.reload();
                    default:
                        if (typeof sel[cur.action] === "function") {
                            sel[cur.action](cur.data);
                        }; // else continue
                    break;
                };
            };
        };


            // Dispatch the AJAX request, and save it to the data object so that
            // is can be referenced and cancelled if need be.

            self.data('ajaxify.xhr', jQuery.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: 'post',
                dataType: options.dataType,
                data: (beforeSubmitIsJquery ? beforeSubmitResult.serialize()
                                            : self.serialize()),
                success: function (/**/) {
                    cleanup();

                    options.onSuccess.apply(that, arguments);
                },
                error: function (/**/) {
                    cleanup();

                    options.onError.apply(that, arguments);
                },
                complete: function (/**/) {
                    options.onComplete.apply(that, arguments);
                }
            }));
```

Comment: Try to set `contentType` to `application/json` in your `.ajax` request.

Comment: I want to offer 200 points for a bounty for this but it won't let me do it sub two days :(

Comment: Already tried adapting the content type: If we switch away from header to plain text or json it loads a new page with the JSON response on it - instead of downloading the response like it does with contentType header (both of which are wrong).

Comment: You shouldn't really need the content type at all. What's triggering the ajax request? An event?

Comment: It's an <input> with preventdefault specified in the javascript.  Gathers all form data and POSTs it.

Comment: Well, I ask because the behavior you describe has all the hallmarks of a double-post caused by an event handler launching an ajax request *followed by* the "native" browser form submit happening. If I were you, I'd make triple-extra-sure that your event handler is either returning "false" or calling "preventDefault", or maybe both :-)

Comment: As a temporary experiment, you could try adding a `<button type="button">` to your form, and wire your handler **only** to that.  A "button"-type button won't submit the form, so if it works when you use that test button for your action, then you've got evidence that you're somehow not neutering that event in the current code.

Comment: When we switch it to button type=button it does not submit at all - problem is we use this Ajaxify function everywhere using type=submit (which worked on all other browsers - stupid us for not testing it in IE first).

Is there anyway to handle this?  Seems IE just ignores preventdefault....

Comment: Since IE ignores preventDefault, try using `return false;` after preventDefault ...

Comment: If either you or Pointy posts as an answer I'll select it as right - you guys both helped.

Comment: Go for it, @drachenstern, and say "hi" to Shreveport for me

Comment: I'll steal the thunder on this one ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I ask because the behavior you describe has all the hallmarks of a double-post caused by an event handler launching an ajax request followed by  the "native" browser form submit happening. If I were you, I'd make triple-extra-sure that your event handler is either returning "false" or calling "preventDefault", or maybe both :-) – Pointy 1 hour ago

My followup: Since IE ignores preventDefault, try using return false; after preventDefault ...

For future reference to other devs: the way that the common libraries tend to do this is they will usually code a block with both methods (preventDefault() and return false;) because this tells each of the major browsers to stop working the event, according to which they listen to. This is more important with legacy IE browsers.

Anyways, glad we could help.

Comment: Just ran into a problem if you could help:  Basically we fixed it by removing type="submit" from the submit button and then in the javascript setting it to live("click" instead of live("submit" (which is apparently broken in IE?)

Comment: Oh man, sorry about that, you caught me after I left work... I will think on this in the morning.

Comment: I thought you had it wired up to an input submit with an onclick that cancelled and returned false. What happens when you put it back to that way? ~~~ Live only works in some browsers, IIRC. there is a workaround I thought for when Live doesn't work, but I'm running a little behind this morning so not able to look up the details on that.  I can certainly look in about 2 or 3 hours and respond then. Hope this helps for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with ASP.NET MVC 4. I was returning a JSONResult. But by changing the return object to this.content fixed this problem.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(AddNewModel model)
{
    /**...*/
    return this.Content(id.ToString());
}
```

So it appears that IE has a problem with a json object being returned, and can be fixed by returning a string.